# Firebase - getRedirectResult not working in Cordova browser

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I have setup Firebase to my Cordova App to authenticate with Facebook which works fine in Android due a workaround I have found. However, in my browser I can't make it work.

Problem: Once I call `signInWithRedirect(provider)` method its redirect to firebase and logs in correctly (checked on firebase's dashboard), then It redirects to my localhost:8000 but it never stops in `getRedirectResult()` method.

No console log errors displayed.

My app set up:

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
 var config = {
            apiKey: "*********",
            authDomain: "*********",
            databaseURL: "*********",
            projectId: "*********",
            storageBucket: "*********",
            messagingSenderId: "*********"
          };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

**login_controller.js**

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

            firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function() {
                firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
                    // This gives you a Google Access Token.
                    // You can use it to access the Google API.
                    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                    // The signed-in user info.
                    var user = result.user;
                    console.log('result '+ result);
                    debugger;

                  }).catch(function(error) {
                    // Handle Errors here.
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    debugger;
                  });
                }).catch(function(error){
                    debugger;
                });
```

**Firebase configuration**

localhost domain added

web env setup

Facebook auth setup

What did I miss?

Comment: In a browser environment, `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` should be called outside the `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)` call. You can also add an `onAuthStateChanged` listener which when the user is not signed in, call signInWithRedirect, otherwise consider as signed in.

Comment: Didn't work..if I called outside getRedirectResult will run before signInWithRedirect throwing and empty result.

Comment: `getRedirectResult` will resolve with an empty result if it is not coming back from a redirect sign-in. typically you should call `signInWithRedirect` when a user clicks to sign-in after you confirm the user is not logged in via `onAuthStateChanged` listener. You add `getRedirectResult` to get that result. But you could already be logged in and calling that will resolve with an empty result.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I set it up like this (it is intertwined with a `plugin` I wrote):

This method gets called when it is identified that a user is not logged in:

```
toggleWebViewWithAuth: function () {
    var win = function(d) {
        console.log("web view toggled, going to auth");

        auth.presentLogin().then(function() {
            auth.getResult();
        });
    };
    var fail = function(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

    cordova.exec(win, fail, "NavigationPlugin", "toggleWebView", []);
}
```

`auth.presentLogin` is an `async` function I made that looks like this:

```
presentLogin: async function () {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    //provider.addScope('default');
    provider.addScope('email');
    //provider.addScope('pages_show_list');

    return firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
},
```

Also in the `auth` variable is:

```
getResult: function () {
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {

        if (result.credential) {
            // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            // ...
        }

        // The signed-in user info.
        app.user = result.user;

        console.log("result.user in presentLogin:", app.user);
    }).then(function() {
        //iosNav.getCurrentTabControllerName();
        iosNav.toggleWebView();
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        alert("Error:", error);

        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
    });
}
```

So now go back and read the `toggleWebViewWithAuth` method that I posted, and you will see how I used it. This makes it so that `getRedirectWithResult` waits for `signInWithRedirect`. All of this can be configured outside of a plugin (without using `cordova.exec`, all that method does on the iOS side is open or close the `UIWebView`) - The most important part is that you just need to make sure to use my `presentLogin` method how I did to present it, calling `getResult` in the `then` block.

Also, for your `js` imports, `firebase-app`, and all of the `firebase` module `js` files, replaced using the global `firebase.js` import. You only need:

```
<script>.../firebase-app.js</script>
<script>.../firebase-auth.js</script>
```